# How to know if a user is logged in?

Tags: asp.net, security

is there anyway I could create a function that receives and username and the function returns if the user is currently logged in into the application?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
this.Page.User.Identity
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`System.Web.Security.MembershipUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) class has an `IsOnline` boolean property, so you could do something like this..

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
if (user != null)
  return user.IsOnline;

// handle User not found here, or just return false..
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Session.Add("CurrentUser", currentUser);
```

Add the user as a session and you should be good. This is for ASP.NET C#, you might want to elaborate more on what you want to do.

```
_currentUser = ([].User)Session["CurrentUser"];

if (_currentUser != null)
{
}
```